# When should I prefer kappa over accuracy for binary classification problems?

Tags: classification, metric, cohens-kappa

I'm using the `caret` package in `R` that provides two kind of metrics for classification problems - accuracy and kappa. When should I prefer one over another?

Comment: Do you know how each measure is calculated?

Comment: Yes. But I have never used kappa in practice.